# Protractor : HTTP method not allowed

Tags: angular, http, protractor, action

This is line which fails :

```
browser.actions().sendKeys(protractor.Key.ESCAPE).perform();
```

Error : `- Failed: HTTP method not allowed`

It works perfectly fine with google chrome, but when launching e2e test with firefox, it doesn't. I don't understand at all the error since I am not doing any HTTP method. I am just pressing the ESC button that's it, there is not GET or PUT OR ... requests I am doing here..

Comment: [Check out this thread](https://github.com/angular/protractor/issues/4757). There may be an issue sending some keys to firefox

Comment: thank you for your answer, I still don't know how am I suppose to use the firefox protractor package to do what I want to do ?

Answer (score 0):

This is known issue in protractor I have also commented in the ticket, take a look [here](https://github.com/angular/protractor/issues/5346)

I suggest you this - https://www.npmjs.com/package/protractor-firefox-support

example:

```
 const support = require('protractor-firefox-support');
module.exports.mouseClick = ({elemSelector, point, tgtIndex} = {}) => {
   const options = {};
   (elemSelector) ? options.selector = elemSelector : null;
   (point) ? options.point = point : null;
   (tgtIndex) ? options.elementIndex = tgtIndex : null;
   return browser.executeScript(support.mouseClick, options);
}
```

Comment: thank you for your answer, I still don't know how am I suppose to use this to sendKeys

Comment: I have edited the above answer and also for more refer the above NPM link you will find out. Happy coding :). 
If this works for you please up-vote and mark as tick for answer

Comment: yeah I still don't see how to rewrite `browser.actions().sendKeys(protractor.Key.ESCAPE).perform();` using that library

Comment: Waiting for this issue to be resolved @Tony

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue. I fixed it by sending the key directly to the desired element.
So instead of

```
browser.actions().sendKeys(protractor.Key.ENTER).perform();
```

I used

```
$('input').sendKeys(protractor.Key.ENTER);
```